# Correcting for restriction of range in multiple regression

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression

I've conducted a multiple linear regression with 3 predictors, A, B, and C, all three on the same scale.

One of the three predictors displays a smaller range than the other two (range A=0.53; B=0.98; C=0.86), as well as a smaller standard deviation (SD A=0.18; B=0.30; C=0.25).This is precisely the predictor that does not show a significant effect, while the other two (B and C) do.

I would like to correct the coefficient (or standardized coefficient) of A for its restricted range.

I have only found corrections for the correlation coefficient, such as Thorndike's case 2 (see, e.g., here: http://pareonline.net/pdf/v14n5.pdf ).

1. How can coefficients in multiple regression be corrected?
   Could I perhaps apply Thorndike's correction to the partial correlation between A and Y, while controlling for B and C?
   (ideally, however, I would like to have a correction of the regression coefficient)
2. The correction requires knowing the unrestricted SD. This is not possible, but I can use the SD of one of the other predictors. The argument would go: "The lack of an effect for A, as opposed to B and C might be due to its restricted range; with this correction we show that assuming for A as large an SD as for B, then A's coefficient would still be small (or is now as large as that for B)". Is this at all sound?

Thank you!

Comment: Probably not sound. You say one predictor have a smaller range than others. But that is what you have observed, and means less information about the corresponding coefficient. This is not a "restriction", t is part of the data. You propose to change the data? that cannot be sound.